# How to Locate the File that Contains Certain HTML element?

Tags: google-chrome

When I use chrome "inspect element", I can find the html element and try to edit it but cannot save the changes. How to locate the file on the server that contains the HTML element so that I can edit it and save it?

Comment: What kind of server is it? What kind of access do you have to it?

Comment: it can turn that  element was generated by javascript, so you will find almost nothing

Comment: In linux like systems `grep -n -R "iwillfindyou" ./*`, in Windows like `find /N "imaybewilltoo" .\*`. Run command in folder with web files, it will show you names of files that contains phrase.

Comment: The HTML response received by the browser can be generated by server-side script like PHP, ASP, Python, etc. There is no need there is even a file containing the inspected element.

Answer (score 2):

You can save your changes by going to the parent tag (the very first tag) on the page, usually html, and right click it, then click "copy as html" and save it into a document.